# Is it possible to sort JIRA tickets in the Reports area?

Tags: jira, reporting

the question is very simple. Scenario is a Scrum Project.
I would need to be able to sort tickets in the Reports are of a Scrum Project. Currently those tickets are separated per area, as **Completed**, **Not Completed**, **Completed out of the Sprint**.

It would help the readability of the report. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Looks like sorting of Jira tickets in the Reports area is not possible now

I see that [requests to be able to sort are logged as a user suggestion but in 'Unresolved' status since 2014](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-10236). You can add your request as a comment and also vote for this.